# IF statement breaks batch script

Tags: batch-file

I'm writing a batch script to extract video files from their directories.
So far, it's going into the directory that matches a specific name. I am then doing a `FOR` loop over every item in that directory. I want to check if an item is a directory (*which I have done previously*), if it is then go into that directory, else do other stuff.

The problem is that the 2nd `IF` statement (*to check whether the item is a directory or not*) is breaking the batch script, giving the error:

> ) was unexpected at this time

If I remove that `IF`, the code executes as expected (*I have clearly labelled which `IF` statement it is in the code*)...

**CODE:**

```
@ECHO off

SET title=%1
SET mp4=".mp4"
SET mkv=".mkv"
SET avi=".avi"
SET minimumSize=300
SET needCompressingDir="E:\Documents\Films\Need_compressing"

CD %needCompressingDir%
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('DIR /B') DO (
    IF %%i == %title% (
        IF EXIST %%i (
            CD %%i
            FOR /f "delims=" %%j IN ('DIR /B') DO (
                rem this 'IF' statement breaks it
                IF EXIST %%j (

                ) ELSE (

                )
            )
        ) ELSE (
            MOVE %%i %needCompressingDir%
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Could any of the file names returned by `%%j` contain spaces? You should try using `if exist "%%j"` (and `if exist "%%i"` earlier) instead.

Comment: @SomethingDark yes, it's entirely possible that that could happen, thanks for the insight and will try that approach when I can

Comment: try with `IF EXIST "%%~j"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read `if /?`:

> ```
> Performs conditional processing in batch programs.
>
> IF [NOT] ERRORLEVEL number command
> IF [NOT] string1==string2 command
> IF [NOT] EXIST filename command
> …
>   command           Specifies the command to carry out if the condition is
>                     met.  Command can be followed by ELSE command which
>                     will execute the command after the ELSE keyword if the
>                     specified condition is FALSE
>
> The ELSE clause must occur on the same line as the command after the IF.  For
> example:
>
>     IF EXIST filename. (
>         del filename.
>     ) ELSE (
>         echo filename. missing.
>     )
> ```

You can see that `command` is **mandatory** part of both `if` and `else` parts. Windows `cmd` / `.bat` interpreter does not accept *empty* command block `()`: it's not considered to be a command. Use at least `REM` comment (a command with no effect):

```
        FOR /f "delims=" %%j IN ('DIR /B') DO (
            rem this 'IF' statement breaks it
            IF EXIST "%%~j\" (
              rem directory
            ) ELSE (
              rem not directory
            )
        )
```

**Updated**: use `IF EXIST "%%~j\"` (note trailing backslash) *to check whether the item is a directory or not*.